# USdt ERC20 1006

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-20-approve, private

I am confused about this "Usdt erc20 1006" . In a website for withdrawal it is written "your Usdt Erc20 1006"..
This is certainly address but which type of address is this.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? The "1006" doesn't have a particular meaning.